# Error in Visual Studio Code : robot.resolveinterpreter not found

Tags: python-3.x, visual-studio, robotframework, robocode

Getting language server Python executable.
Waiting for RobotFramework (python) Language Server to finish activating...
Starting RobotFramework Language Server with args: C:\Users\A182573\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37,-u,c:\Users\A182573.vscode\extensions\robocorp.robotframework-lsp-0.41.0\src\robotframework_ls_*main*_.py,-v
[Error - 17:01:09] Starting client failed
Error: Launching server using command C:\Users\A182573\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37 with args: -u,c:\Users\A182573.vscode\extensions\robocorp.robotframework-lsp-0.41.0\src\robotframework_ls_*main*_.py,-v failed.
at serverOptions (c:\Users\A182573.vscode\extensions\robocorp.robotframework-lsp-0.41.0\vscode-client\out\extension.js:279:19)
at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
It was not possible to start the Robot Framework Language Server. Please update the related `robot.language-server` configurations.
Launching server using command C:\Users\A182573\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37 with args: -u,c:\Users\A182573.vscode\extensions\robocorp.robotframework-lsp-0.41.0\src\robotframework_ls_*main*_.py,-v failed.
Error: Launching server using command C:\Users\A182573\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37 with args: -u,c:\Users\A182573.vscode\extensions\robocorp.robotframework-lsp-0.41.0\src\robotframework_ls_*main*_.py,-v failed.
at serverOptions (c:\Users\A182573.vscode\extensions\robocorp.robotframework-lsp-0.41.0\vscode-client\out\extension.js:279:19)
at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
Found Workspace Folder Value configuration: robotframework-lsp - Robot Framework: Launch .robot file.
Found Workspace Value configuration: robotframework-lsp - Robot Framework: Launch .robot file.